# Why would I need this variable declaration to make my code work?

Tags: jquery, css, modernizr

I have this piece of code and it actually works fine, yet I have a spurious line in there and it won't work without it for some reason.

It picks up the hover color from the css via jquery and animates that hover (between colors) for browsers that dont have css transitions. ( I am using modernizr to detect the feature). The problem is that if I remove the variable declaration `var ie8and9dec = quickbarcolorhover;` ( which has no other use at all, it's just there to trigger whatever makes this work )  then it will not work at all for IE8 and IE9 ... (*so probably just wont work at all as I think all the other browsers I've used don't need this code in the first place*).

Does anyone know why this would be the case? It will also work if I replace the declaration with `console.log(quickbarcolorhover);`, and that's how I discovered it. I would rather not have this spurious piece of code if I can avoid it.

```
$(function() {
    var quickbar = $(".no-csstransitions #quick-bar a");
    quickbarcolor = quickbar.css("color");

    quickbar.hover(function () {
        if ( $(this).css("color") != quickbarcolor) {
            quickbarcolorhover = $(this).css("color");
        }
        var ie8and9dec = quickbarcolorhover; /* this dec has no purpose but code wont work without it */
        $(this).children().css("color", quickbarcolor).animate({ color: quickbarcolorhover } ,400 );
    }, function() {
        $(this).children().animate({ 'color': quickbarcolor} ,400 )
    }  
    );
});
```

Comment: This has got to be masking some underlying problem...

Comment: Do you have variable declarations for `quickbarcolor` and `quickbarcolorhover` anywhere?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard no ... and I just noticed if I define them with anything then the code doesnt work either ... I'm also getting an undefined error for quickbarcolorhover

Comment: Probably because these have to be global for some framework or library you're using. What are you using apart from jQuery and Modernizr?

Comment: Do you have a link to somewhere where you can reproduce this (I think Matt Ball is right, so you probably will not be able to reproduce this in a JsFiddle, because the 'underlying problem' is somewhere else and will not be included in the JsFiddle).

Comment: @11684 No those vars are just local to that function they are not relevant to anything else at all, quickbar is just for caching `$(".no-csstransitions #quick-bar a")` and quickbar hover just holds the result of `$(this).css("color")`. Other than modernizr and jquery I'm using boostrap but like I said those vars are just local. This is part of a pretty large wordpress theme so I cant do a fiddle or anything and it's in local dev. I think I agree with Matt Ball too so I will just do a reduced test case here instead.

Comment: @MattBall thanks I recon you must be right

Comment: @byronyasgur Omitting the `var` keyword when you declare a variable makes the variable global AFAIK.

Comment: @11684 yes it does, I presume you mean line 3, that's an error on my part, but I don't think it has a bearing on it, unless some other code had defined quickbarcolor. I am getting to the bottom of a reduced test case instead, so I'm disassembling the entire thing. It wasn't my finest coding moment anyway so I will either completely rewrite it from scratch, or else I will just dump the whole idea and let IE9 users have a non animated hover ... so it's not that big of an issue anyway. I mainly posted here in case it was some bug or something, but I think it was more likely to be my rubbish code.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it's of any help to anyone else I will describe what I did to fix this.

I was working with wordpress and I discovered that wordpress already includes jQuery UI; so what I did was to remove the part of the JqueryUI code that I had originally been using for the animate functionality ( there is a plugin which can be used either but I had chosen to include the JqueryUI code ) So now I replaced this code with enqueues (in my functions.php file) to both jqueryUI core and JqueryUI effects core, thus including the JqueryUI by a completely different ( and better in wordpress terms) method.

Then the code I used was slightly changed too, but in reality I don't think the code was the problem as it may have been to do with the jQueryUI code that I was using being out of sync with the Jquery code included in wordpress.

```
$(function() {
    var quickbar = $(".no-csstransitions #quick-bar a");
    var quickbarcolor = quickbar.css("color");

    quickbar.hover(function () {
            if ( $(this).css("color") != quickbarcolor) quickbarcolorhover = $(this).css("color");
            $(this).find("*").css("color", quickbarcolor).animate({ color: quickbarcolorhover } , 400 );
        }, function() {
            $(this).find("*").animate({ 'color': quickbarcolor} ,400 )
        }
    );
});
```